# Remember me functionality using UISwitch and NSUserDefaults swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

Im looking to implement the Remember Me functionality in Swift 3 with UISwitch and NSUserDefaults, not using any library. What do you suggest me?

Answer (score 6):

This Worked for me

Following outlets i connected

```
loginTxt  - username textfield
passwordTxt -  password textfield
rememberSwitch - switch
```

code

```
    func viewDidLoad() {

        rememberSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.stateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        let defaults: UserDefaults? = UserDefaults.standard

// check if defaults already saved the details

        if defaults?.bool(forKey: "ISRemember") {
            loginTxt.text = defaults?.value(forKey: "SavedUserName")
            passwordTxt.text = defaults?.value(forKey: "SavedPassword")
            rememberSwitch.setOn(true, animated: false)
        }
        else {
            rememberSwitch.setOn(false, animated: false)
        }
    }

    func stateChanged(_ switchState: UISwitch) {

        let defaults: UserDefaults? = UserDefaults.standard
        if switchState.isOn() {
            defaults?.set(true, forKey: "ISRemember")
            defaults?.set(loginTxt.text, forKey: "SavedUserName")
            defaults?.set(passwordTxt.text, forKey: "SavedPassword")
        }
        else {
            defaults?.set(false, forKey: "ISRemember")
            }
            }
```